# How can I rearrange the outputfile in order to obtain the numbers in lane and separated by a blank space?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, positional-parameter

Here's my script. It takes only 4 positional parameters. The output should be all the positional parameters, the number of characters that each one has and the first character of each one.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -r param.out
declare -i cont
cont=$#
if [ $cont -eq 4 ]
then
  echo "Positional parameters" >> param.out
  echo $* >> param.out
  echo "Number of characters of each positional parameter" >> param.out
  echo -n $1 | wc -c >> param.out
  echo -n $2 | wc -c >> param.out
  echo -n $3 | wc -c >> param.out
  echo -n $4 | wc -c >> param.out
  echo "First character of each parameter" >> param.out
  echo $1 | head -c 1 >> param.out
  echo $2 | head -c 1 >> param.out
  echo $3 | head -c 1 >> param.out
  echo $4 | head -c 1 >> param.out
else
   echo "Error"
  exit
fi
```

With an input of `./file 12 23 34 456` The obtained file is the following one:

```
Positional parameters

    12 23 34 456

Number of characters of each positional parameter

    2
    2
    2
    3

First character of each parameter

    1234
```

The ideal would be obtaining the outputs as the first one `(12 23 34 456)`

PD. I know this could be done using a `for`/`while` in order to avoid repetitions of echo but I'm learning bash :/

Comment: Please have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

> `echo -n $1 | wc -c >> param.out`

`wc` appends a new line to it's output, which has to be removed or replaced by a space in order to the get number of characters of each parameter on a single line. You could do that with `sed`:

```
echo -n $1 | wc -c | sed 's/\n/ /' >> param.out
```

> `echo $1 | head -c 1 >> param.out`

Use `echo` to append a space to the first character of a parameter:

```
echo "$(echo $1 | head -c 1) " >> param.out
```